# Are there any embeddable socks proxy servers that tunnels traffic through a remote host via ssh?

Tags: c++, proxy, ssh, socks, tunneling

ssh -D 9191 ronald@ssh.somehost.com will create a socks proxy locally that will tunnel all traffic through the remote host. Is it possible to build this in to an application C++ or C and make it possible for this application direct all its traffic through the tunnel?

Short question:
Are there any embeddable socks proxy servers that tunnels traffic through a remote host via ssh? just like ssh -D xxxx ...

Comment: It seems like i have to implement the socks proxy myself and then forward using channels with [libssh](http://api.libssh.org/master/group__libssh__channel.html#gae86b0704a1f2bdebb268b55567f7f47b). Not sure yet but it seems like the way forward.